# How to disable Eclipse's automatic close quotes in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, eclipse

I need to disable Eclipse's automatic close quotes and parenthesis.

For example, hitting a single `"` it will lead to:

```
"<smt>"
```

Any idea about how to disable this feature?

UPDATE: It happen only when using United State international keyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `Preferences > Java > Editor > Typing` and uncheck the Automatically Close `Strings` and `Parentheses` options.

Comment: FYI even after doing this it still auto-closes quotes in CSS files. Anyone know how to disable this in CSS files as well?

Comment: @thdoan that's a missing feature. Feel free to vote https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=562877